# python environment case senstivity - os.environ[...]

Tags: python

I need to access the process' environment block in a platform-independent manner.

The python [os module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) don't specify anything about case-sensitivity of the `os.environ` / `os.getenv`.  Experimenting on my ubuntu and win7 dev box's, I see that os.environ is case sensitive on linux but not on windows (This mirrors the behavior of `set` on both platforms)

Since dict's are obviously case-senstive for string keys, it appears that the value returned by `os.environ` is only *duck-typed* as a dict...

Question:
**Where/How should I be able to find the definitive answer** on this behavior?  I would rather have a real answer than just empirically determine it :)

Alternatively, is os.getenv(...) a better api to use? why?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your exact problem? Windows in general (afaik) handles Paths, Variables, etc. case-insensitive, where linux is case-sensitive. You can therefore access the PATH variable with 'PATH' in both cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the documentation doesn't specify the behaviour and you want to discover the answer yourself, you can look in the source code. In this case you can get the source code for `os.py` online at http://svn.python.org/:

- [`os.py` (Python trunk)](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/os.py).
- [`os.py` (Python 2.7)](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/os.py).

The comments in the code say:

```
elif name in ('os2', 'nt'):  # Where Env Var Names Must Be UPPERCASE
    # But we store them as upper case
    # ...
else:  # Where Env Var Names Can Be Mixed Case
    # ...
```

You can also see a difference in the implementations - `key.upper()` is used instead of `key` on Windows:

Linux:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    putenv(key, item)
    self.data[key] = item
```

Windows:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    putenv(key, item)
    self.data[key.upper()] = item
```

Comment: yes, this is always a way to figure out what is currently done.  IMHO this behavior should be documented somehow, though - am I wrong there?

Comment: @mike How could it be any other way? The Python implementation has no choice but to follow the platform. I'm really struggling to see what is causing you difficulty.

Comment: @David Heffernan one view is that OS.py should follow exactly the conventions of the underlying platform, another is that it should behave consistently/portably between platforms.  These are not necessary mutually exclusive.  As noted in a different comment, the doc author says "as long as the same functionality is available, it uses the same interface", which to me implies it could be case-senstive on both.

Comment: It looks like examining the actual implementation is as good as I'm going to get.  Note, that from 2.7 (what @Mark Byers originally linked to) and 3.2, the relevant code has changed significantly.  It still seems to do the same thing, but not as easy to prove by code inpsection.  I'll accept this ans.

Comment: @mike It would not be possible to implement case-sensitive environment variables on Windows. It would not be possible to implement case-insenstive environment variables on Mac or Linux. That's all I have to say. What you perhaps don't understand is that Python does not hold these variables but the system does.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure it would be - for instance, case insensitive set on unix - choose a conventions (eg store uppercase) and convert to that before setting.

Comment: @mike that would make it impossible to read some variables. Clearly this misunderstanding is the source of the question.

Comment: @mike I'd agree the sparsity of docs on character case needs improvement. Looking thru 2.7 & 3.30 docs I noticed first lines in both a) 'A mapping object representing the string environment.' and b) check os.name (ie posix, nt etc) or sys.platform - is this one of those grey areas b/w OS and python idioms breaking down? Write code accordingly.

Comment: @mike platform 2.3+ is a better bet to find specific system information ~ http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/platform.html#module-platform

Answer (score 1):

Platform independence often means getting worse of all platforms. So for a platform-independent manner you have assume that environment variables are case-sensitive but never try to rely on this (i.e. not create variables with same names in different case intentionally) but be able to handle it. Otherwise you may screw up on non-Windows.

As for what platforms are case-sensitive and what are not - simply. Windows is not case-sensitive, and Unix-like OSs are case sensitive, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Case_sensitive
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Case_insensitivity

For exotic operating systems you have to check its documentation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is common knowledge - doesn't say anything about whether os.environ would/should replicate the behavior.

Comment: @mike: Come-on, that Python interface is nothing but a wrapper around OS calls. You cannot throw in something else and pretend it is OS environment - in that case it won't work with the rest of the system.

Comment: Yes, the OS.py wrapper leverages platform-specific under the hood - however another, equally valid, point would be that OS.py could attempt to provide an abstraction of the underlying platform that is as consistent as possible across different platforms.  The doc author seems to allude to this goal, with phrases such "as long as the same functionality is available, it uses the same interface" . . .

Comment: @mike: You cannot make it consistent, just cannot. What if there is two variables "Var" and "VAR" in Linux, with different values? Should your consistent interface randomly disregard one of those? or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand how standardizing on one or another would not introduce serious violations of the principle of least astonishment.

On windows, programmers are used to case insensitivity... why would a windows-only programmer expect to have to picky about this? Note that there is no possible way to implement case-sensitive environment variables here, that option simply doesn't work.

In the linux world, ENVVAR and envvar are two different variables, you *cannot* standardize to the windows mechanism without potentially hiding information.

In the version that is implemented, you force the developer to specify upper or lower case for a cross-platform app. The case specification is irrelevant on windows, and you'd have to do it anyways for *nix.