# Why python uppercases all environment variables in windows

Tags: python, windows

Is there any reason why os.environ contains all environment variables uppercase on Windows?, I don't understand why (only on windows) it doesn't load them on using the same case as it is defined ?

Is there an equivalent implementation of os.environment that loads the environment variable information without modifying them for Windows?

thanks

Comment: Windows environment variable names are case-insensitive. That might be the answer to _why_.

Comment: Related: [python environment case senstivity - os.environ\[...\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7797269)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Windows environment variables are case *insensitive*, but a Python dictionary is case sensitive. By uppercasing all entries, you ensure that you'll always be able to match entries.

Quoting from the Python [`os.py` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py#l411):

```
elif name in ('os2', 'nt'):  # Where Env Var Names Must Be UPPERCASE
    # But we store them as upper case

# ... 

else:  # Where Env Var Names Can Be Mixed Case
```

Note that the `os.environ` object translates *all* access to uppercase, including searches:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    putenv(key, item)
    self.data[key.upper()] = item
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data[key.upper()]

# ...

def has_key(self, key):
    return key.upper() in self.data
def __contains__(self, key):
    return key.upper() in self.data
def get(self, key, failobj=None):
    return self.data.get(key.upper(), failobj)
```

This means that if a program fails to find `os.environ['windir']`, then the value *is not set*.

If you **have** to have access to the original values, grab them from the `nt` module:

```
import nt
nt.environ
```

That's the raw initial dictionary as passed in by the OS, unaltered:

```
>>> import nt
>>> sorted(nt.environ.keys())
['ALLUSERSPROFILE', 'APPDATA', 'COMPUTERNAME', 'ComSpec', 'CommonProgramFiles', 'CommonProgramFiles(x86)', 'CommonProgramW6432', 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK', 'HOMEDRIVE', 'HOMEPATH', 'LOCALAPPDATA', 'LOGONSERVER', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS', 'OS', 'PATHEXT', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION', 'PROMPT', 'PSModulePath', 'PUBLIC', 'Path', 'ProgramData', 'ProgramFiles', 'ProgramFiles(x86)', 'ProgramW6432', 'SESSIONNAME', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK', 'SystemDrive', 'SystemRoot', 'TEMP', 'TMP', 'USERDNSDOMAIN', 'USERDOMAIN', 'USERNAME', 'USERPROFILE', 'windir', 'windows_tracing_flags', 'windows_tracing_logfile']
```

Comment: Ok, do you know if there is a way to get the original environment variables keys/values on python? I'm running a program (with twisted) that reads environment variable in a case sensitive way, so it isn't finding windir because we pass it as WINDIR.

Comment: @MariangeMarcano: That cannot be the issue; the `os.environ` *object* will uppercase searches too.

Comment: The issue is we are not using python to search the environment variable. We invoke another program.

Comment: @MariangeMarcano: Then show us the code on how you invoke that other program. The issue is not `os.environ['WINDIR']` vs. `os.environ['windir']`; on Windows, the two statements *are equivalent*.

Comment: sure, I agree that's not the problem, we are using CI/buildbot to run builds, we invoke a jamplus script (and the problem is that jamplus it reads environment variable in a case sensitive way) 

buildbot runs the process this way 

from twisted.internet import reactor

.... 

        return reactor.spawnProcess(processProtocol, executable, argv, env, path, usePTY=usePTY)

env param has what we read from os.environ causing the uppercase issue when running jamplus

Comment: @MariangeMarcano: Right, that was not clear from your question. You are passing on the `os.environ` dictionary to a 3rd-party process that *is* broken when it comes to Windows environment variables. I added a workaround.

Comment: It is still inappropriate for a Windows program, such as Python, to change the case of an environment variable set by the user, since Windows environment variable names are case-preserving.

Comment: Previous comment applies to...  when passing the environment to the next program.

Comment: Thank you for quoting the comments in the code so that we know _why_ it does it on windows.  Unfortunately, the author of that code is wrong & introduced it's own bugs when running poorly ported apps to windows from your python script.  Thankfully popen/submodule based launching of child apps can take an optional environment dictionary that will not have it's keys upcased.

Comment: ugh `nt` didn't work for me. They keys in that collection were all upper case as well even though they're not on the system. v3.10

Answer (score 2):

Windows case insensitivity is a pain. Why would they do that? You can understand why searches should be case insensitive, but in most cases defined content should keep the exact value. Why? Well from experience it causes so many problems. I've never come across an issue where I've thought, "oh why wasn't that uppercased or lowercased?".

From a Python point of view, why would they do that? Windows stores the key case sensitively, I'm guessing it is only some functions that get the value in a case insensitive manner, because I know for a fact that not all access functions do. I think MKS can tell the difference.

Don't force platform specific behaviour (and be careful with forcing other behaviour) in an interface. Provide an alternative method to force case insensitivity, if required.