# How to get correct case of windows environment variable in Sublime Text

Tags: windows, environment-variables, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am trying to run my build script (bat file calling gnu make) on Windows 7 from within Sublime as a custom build system:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "mlabuild",
        "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "ba.bat"]
    }
]
```

I have added set to the start of the bat file, which shows (amongst others)

```
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
```

If I run the same bat file from a command line, it shows

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
```

This is probably because the environment is taken from Python (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023238/why-python-uppercases-all-environment-variables-in-windows)).

The problem is, that GNU make is case sensitive, so the following from one  of the makefiles

```
   COMPILER_BASEDIR=$(ProgramFiles)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 6.0\cr16c
```

has `$(ProgramFiles)` expanded to nothing, and the build fails.

How do I get correct case on the build environment?

I cannot change the makefile, because it is shared with many other developers.

I tried both Sublime Text 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved it in the makefile, by defining `ProgramFiles` with the correct case in the beginning.

```
###############################################################################
# Sublime Text capiptalizes the environment, but gnumake is case sensitive
###############################################################################
ifndef ProgramFiles
ProgramFiles=$(PROGRAMFILES)
endif
```

If anyone finds a solution, that provides the correct case in the environment, please let me know.