# Why does providing an environment to my Python subprocess cause it to abort?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, case-sensitive

I am attempting to run a subprocess through Python of an executable developed by my company; let's call it `prog.exe`.  I can run this command just fine on from CMD; I can run it just fine through `subprocess`; but if I try to pass `env` to `subprocess`, I get an error:

```
C:\Users\me> prog.exe -h
prog V1.2.2 (Build 09-07-2016.12.52)
more dummy help text...
C:\Users\me> python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> subprocess.Popen("prog.exe -h").wait()
prog V1.2.2 (Build 09-07-2016.12.52)
more dummy help text...
0
>>> 
>>> subprocess.Popen("prog.exe -h", env=os.environ).wait()
```

After executing that command, the following dialog opens informing me that "`prog.exe` has stopped working" and "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...":

[image: prog.exe has stopped working]

which turns into "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.":

[image: prog.exe has truly stopped working]

When I close that dialog, the subprocess exits with an error:

```
255
>>>
```

What is going on?  I thought that `os.environ` is essentially passed as `env` to `subprocess` if I do not specify `env`.  So why when I specify it does it cause my program to die?

I have tried Python 3.5 and Python 2.7 with same results.

Comment: Try the original `nt.environ` instead.

Comment: ``nt.environ`` worked.  So ``os.environ`` keys are all upper case?  I was not aware of this, but I could see that causing problems.

Comment: Ah, mixed case explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023293/1449189

Comment: It shouldn't cause a problem considering the `GetEnvironmentVariable` function is case insensitive. But maybe this program is building its own copy of the environment, like what Python does, but without taking into account that it should be case insensitive.

Comment: @eryksun You are probably correct.  I've changed my scripts and everything is running well now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [in an older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023293/1449189), the `os.environ` keys are stored/accessed in a case insensitive manner.  `nt.environ` preserves the case of the environment variables as passed into the Python process.

In this case, `prog.exe` is evidently accessing environment variables in a case sensitive manner, thus it requires the original mixed-case environment to be passed in.

Using `nt.environ` rather than `os.environ` resolves the issue:

```
>>> import nt
>>> subprocess.Popen("prog.exe -h", env=nt.environ).wait()
prog V1.2.2 (Build 09-07-2016.12.52)
more dummy help text...
0
>>>
```

Comment: If you can, submit this as a bug report for the program. I rarely see even Microsoft respect a consistent case for environment variables. They frequently switch between camel case and upper case (e.g. `Path` and `PATH`).